# EC2 html page will not load

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have spent hours trying to figure this out to no avail.

my ec2 ip will not load the index page https://18.222.15.39/

I configured the security settings to allow port 80, 443, etc.

I tried following this tutorial but no success

[Can't access site on EC2 instance via public ip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10253484/cant-access-site-on-ec2-instance-via-public-ip)

Comment: Have you tried accessing index page from within EC2? using curl? If that works, post what network configuration you have. VPC, subnets, NACL, security groups etc

Comment: it worked for the  http version

Comment: Do You have 

`HTTP / TCP / 80 / 0.0.0.0/0`
`HTTP / TCP / 80 / ::/0`


`HTTPS / TCP / 443 / 0.0.0.0/0`
`HTTPS / TCP / 443 / ::/0`

Inbound rules in your Security Group?

`::/0`  is for the IPv6 address

Comment: If you login to the instance and then `curl https://localhost`, does it work? This will test whether content is being served on port 443, without having to pass through the network.